# ADALiOS 2.2.5 and 2.2.6 does not work in below iOS 9

Tags: ios, azure, adal

In my application I have updated to latest ADALiOS library versions 2.2.6 (tried with 2.2.5 as well) to support for iOS 10 but after updating it stopped working in below iOS 9. If you try to open webview for WAAD login then login screen loads and immediately gets disappear in below iOS 9 and stating with a message `"The network connection was lost."` Please help me on it. The same is working fine with iOS 9 and iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it on simulator iOS8.1, but things worked.

Maybe you can try restarting the simulator as suggested by this? ([NSURLConnection GET request returns -1005, "the network connection was lost"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797339/nsurlconnection-get-request-returns-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost))

Comment: I am getting this issue on iOS 8.4 version.

Comment: It does not work for me in iOS 8.1 too. Login view disappearing immediately.